# Access object of to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have an object with a to-many relationship. It goes Workout<-->>Workout Score. If I have the workout score, how can I access the workout? I am using Parse.com.

Assuming workoutScore is a PFObject, and has been retrieved, I have a relationship called whichWorkout on it. The object returned is the workout, however I cannot access it's properties. Am I doing something wrong?

```
// Assuming this score has been retrieved by a PFQuery
PFObject *workoutScore;
PFObject *actualWorkout = workoutScore[@"whichWorkout"];
// Now when I try to access a property of actualWorkout, I can't
NSString *name = actualWorkout[@"name"];
```

If I just query for the actual workout, the same code works. Is there any way to access properties of objects retrieved via pointer relationships using Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a query on the workoutScore you should use `[query include:@"workout"]`. This will pull the object that is being pointed to (the actualWorkout) and get everything you need in one call

```
PFQuery query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WorkoutScore"];
[query includeKey:@"workout"];
[query findAllInBackground....
```

The other option is to call fetch on the actual workout. This will be a second call after you have fetched the workoutScore. If you know you are going to need the workout probably better to get it during the query with the include.

```
PFObject *actualWorkout = workoutScore[@"whichWorkout"];

// There are asynchronous versions of fetch too
// which would be recommended
[actualWorkout fetch]; 

// actualWorkout will now have its data.
NSString *name = actualWorkout[@"name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If WorkoutScore has a back pointer to Workout (it looks like it does from your code, called whichWorkout), then it's easy.  When querying WorkoutScore, use `includeKey:` to aggressively fetch the related object:

```
[workoutScoreQuery includeKey:@"whichWorkout"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the many to many relationship is a PFRelation, you'll have to query it as a second step

```
PFRelation *relation = [parseObject relationForKey:@"relationName"];
PFQuery *query = [[relation query] findObjectsInBackground:...];
```

If the many to many relationship is just an array of pointers, you need to tell the query to include the actual data:

```
[workoutScoreQuery includeKey:@"whichWorkout"];
```